# Highlight TODO and other keywords in the Text Editor (gedit) isn't working

Tags: themes, gedit, c, text-editor, syntax-highlighting

I'm using the Text Editor (gedit) for couple months.
I have downloaded the `inkpot` theme because it seems good.

https://gist.github.com/carmelom/14e74271d4c03f3028f0e050be0e7f0a

The problem is, it's doesn't highlight any `FIXME` or `TODO` words.

If I change my Text Editor to use an other theme, it works and these words get highlighted.

Can you look at the code of the theme and tell me why and if it can be fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably https://github.com/mattcan/solarized-gedit/blob/master/solarized-dark.xml#L100

Comment: @muru can you elaborate? I mean you gave me a link to an other theme.

Comment: I linked to a specific line in that theme `<style name="def:note" ...`

Comment: Works like a charm! @muru Thank you!